# Detect is when a windows service has been deleted

Tags: c#, windows, logging, service

Is there a way to detect when a windows service has been deleted? I've checked the event log but it doesn't pick up deleted actions only added.

I believe there may be a way using audit logs but I'm unsure how to do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there is no trace of service deletion in *Event* or *Audit* logs, what you *can* do is create a small console app that detects if a service exists and attach this app to `Windows Task Scheduler` such that it is scheduled to execute based on frequency or a *Trigger* that you can customize to your *requirements* such that you will receive an alert if a service has been *added* or *removed* etc..

> The console app is designed such that on the first run, it logs all
>   the services on the system and on the subsequent runs it will be
>   tracking changes made on the services via `servicesRemoved` and
>   `servicesAdded`, with this we can decide what action to take when a
>   service has been *modified*

*Console App: **ServiceDetector.exe***

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"C:\AdminLocation\ServicesLog.txt";

    var currentServiceCollection = ServiceController.GetServices().Select(s => s.ServiceName).ToList(); //Queries the most current Services from the machine

    if (!File.Exists(path)) //Creates a Log file with current services if not present, usually means the first run
    {
        // Assumption made is that this is the first run
        using (var text = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            currentServiceCollection.ForEach((s) => text.WriteLine(s));
        }
        return;
    }

    // Fetches the recorded services from the Log
    var existingServiceCollection = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

    var servicesRemoved = existingServiceCollection.Except(currentServiceCollection).ToList();
    var servicesAdded = currentServiceCollection.Except(existingServiceCollection).ToList();

    if (!servicesAdded.Any() && !servicesRemoved.Any())
    { Console.WriteLine("No services have been added or removed"); return; }

    //If any services has been added
    if (servicesAdded.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One or more services has been added");
        using (var text = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            servicesAdded.ForEach((s) => text.WriteLine(s));
        }
        return;
    }
    //Service(s) may have been deleted, you can choose to record it or not based on your requirements
    Console.WriteLine("One or more services has been removed");

}
```

*Scheduling Task*

Windows Start > Task Scheduler > Create Basic Task > Set Trigger > Attach your exe > Finish

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, The problem with this is it could be any service i wont particularly know the name of the service that gets deleted.

Comment: I think this is the best approach. I'll create a service that runs on startup and loop and detect when a service is deleted and either write to a file or raise and event. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right that deleting a Windows Service does cause an event to be added to the System Event Log (source: https://superuser.com/questions/1238311/how-can-we-detect-if-a-windows-service-is-deleted-is-there-an-event-log-id-for-i).

AFAIK there's no audit policy to audit the deletion of a service and I think if there were I think it would be listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-process-tracking

I assume polling `ServiceController.GetServices()` is out of the question because your program might not be running when the service is uninstalled?

Comment: Exactly my process might not be running.

Comment: Ok, I think you're out of luck then @BillyDay

Comment: Why not just check a file associated with that service... e.g myService.exe

Comment: you could also check the registry to make sure the service exists HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services, if you wanted to make sure any service wasn't deleted you'll have to add your own cache

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to build instrumentation, until you learn what constitutes good instrumentation. My how-to is essentially taken directly from the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation.

**Instrumentation How-to**

http://www.powersemantics.com/e.html

- Non-integrated
- Primary data only
- Pull not push
- Organized by process
- Never offline

The solution to the problem of measuring indicators exists, but you're stuck conceptualizing how to also have "push-based" instrumentation signal another system. As my E article explains, instruments should always pull data never push it. Event-driven signalling is a potential point of failure you don't need.

To clear up any indecisiveness or doubts you may have about building a separate application, monitors are normally independent (*non-integrated* as Wikipedia says) processes. So saying your monitor "might not be running" means you have not chosen to build a real non-integrated monitor, one which is always on. Your consumer system doesn't correctly model instrumentation, because it *integrates* the check in its own process.

Separate these responsibilities and proceed. Decide how often the instrument should reasonably poll for deleted services and poll the data with a timer. If you use the API call simon-pearson suggested, you can also detect when services have been added. Of course, the monitor needs to locally cache a copy of the service list so that indicators can infer what's been added or removed.